# How do I opt out of authentication when using identityServer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, wif

I'm trying WIF and using identityServer. My question is how can one opt of requiring auth on controller or controller methods ( ASP.NET MVC 4 ). I have previously used [AllowAnonymous] attribute. Anyone have any samples of how to do this? This code still redirects to the identityServer for login.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This code still redirects to the identityServer for login.

I hope you didn't put the following in your web.config, did you:

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Most WIF tutorials show this, but if you are writing an ASP.NET MVC application you should control authorization with `[Authorize]` and `[AllowAnonymous]` attributes.

Comment: yes this is in my web.config.  should I remove that entirely and rely on the attributing? Thanks. I'll try that.